# Runtime error 1004 with "EnvelopeVisible = True"

Tags: vba

I have the following code to activate an email window in Excel 2010. I have the exact same code in another macro, and it works fine there. In both cases, the macro is called by a CommandButton on the active sheet. I can't figure out why the error with one workbook and not the other. Ideas?
When I run this macro, I get the error:

Run time error '1004':
Method 'EnvelopeVisible' of Object '_Workbook' failed

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

    With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
        .Item.To = "recipient"
        .Item.Subject = "some words"
        .Introduction = "some words"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you running it on the same machine or different?

Comment: Same machine. I can open both workbooks in separate windows and run the macro. One works, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out--seems that something has to be selected in order to call the envelope. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with some other alternative way.

The issue was occurring due to the envelop object activation within Citrix.
I googled and used the HTML conversion function, where we are converting the Excel range as HTML and pasting that into the mail body.
With above approach, I was able to meet the objective.

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```